# All numbers twice in a 7x7 Minesweeper grid

Tags: combinatorics, minesweeper

Can you place mines on a 7x7 Minesweeper grid such that each number from 0 to 8 appears exactly twice?

A similar question about a 5x5 grid: 
[All numbers in a 5x5 Minesweeper grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89158/all-numbers-in-a-5x5-minesweeper-grid)

Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It feels like there's more slack in here for other solutions

1.

> [image: Solution 1]

2.

> [image: Solution 2]

3.

> [image: Solution 3]

Comment: Good luck solving any of those. :D

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way of completing this puzzle:

> [image]

Comment: This answer is also correct and I love the symmetry. Unfortunately I can only accept the first correct answer.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Please post an answer with $MathJax$ so that l can see it. I can't access lmgur images. See my profile.